# How do I get the values in php variables from a selected row in phpgrid?

Tags: phpgrid

I am trying to populate fields in a html form getting data values from a row selected by a user in phpgrid. So the phpgrid has a table from the database and I want to select a row which then gets populated in a html form. I tried using AJAX variables but nothing work. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You can do by creating a ShowSelectedRows function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowSelectedRows(){
    var rows = getSelRows();
        var dataIDs = $('#Data2').getDataIDs(); // #Data2 is the name given to your table
        gdata = $('#Data2').jqGrid('getRowData', rows[0]);
        console.log(gdata);
    }
</script>
```

Ensure to enable multiselect for rows. Hope it helps!